# Normalizing a database with user, a date, and check-ins

Tags: database, foreign-keys, normalization

I'm designing a database and I'm looking for the best way to format the tables. The users can check in and check out boxes, tapes, CDs, and other types of media. I want a history of who has checked out what and at what times. Here is a simplified version of my current schema:

```
User(id, first_name, last_name)
Box(id, description)
Tape(id, description)
CD(id, title)
check_in(id, in_date, out_date, fk_user)

check_in_history(id, fk_checkin, media_type)
```

I have a table for the User and the different types of media. The check-ins are also stored in a separate table. For the check-in history I have the foreign key of the check-in table along with a field for the media type so I can determine which table, and thus which type of media is being referred to by the check-in. Still, this seems like a kludge and feels inefficient. Is there a better way to design this database?

**Edit:** The different types of media have a lot of different properties that I left out for simplicity so they can't be in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way; Have one table for media with id,type,description, title.
The check_in table needs to have a link to the media table. Thus the check_in links the user and the media.

There is no reason for a history table. The check_in table will have a history of all loans.

Comment: The different types of media have a lot of different properties that I left out for simplicity so they can't be in the same table.